# Texture along the shape of the mesh

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, texturing, uv

I have been looking for a solution to this problem for a long time, and getting to this was my last alternative. I intend to correctly texture my mesh as the image below:

[image]

As you can see, it is an every day situation but I would like to know how to solve it in the best possible way without making an extensive mapping of the figure that forces me to make a larger UV texture image in every sense.

I tried many ways, but I did not get the desired effect. I think that my biggest problem in this situation is that English is not my native language, and therefore, I have difficulties to find the exact search title of my problem. (please consider this before mark my question as possible duplicate)

Thank you very much for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Follow Active Quads.  The problem you're seeing is because the geometry doesn't have a lot of detail so it's not giving you nice curves.  Add a Subdivision Surface modifier and you'll get better results:

[image]

You may need to tweak the UVs a bit still in a couple of spots but I think you'll get really close with this.